# yii dropdownlist Options value

Tags: php, yii

I am new to Yii and learning.I am trying to add cities in dropdownList and everything is seems to be working fine. The problem is that I am getting city id along with city name in dropdownlist and only id is selectable and visible which is not the requirement.

[Drop down List for city](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vnzR.png)

Here is the code:

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <?= $form->labelEx($model, 'user_city_id', array('class' => ' control-label')); ?>
        <div class="clearfix">
            <?= $form->dropDownList($model, 'user_city_id', CHtml::listData($model_cities, 'city_id', 'city_country_id','city_name'), array('class' => 'select2')); ?>
        </div>
```

$model is user model which contain the user_city_id

This is how I am fetching the city model:

```
$model_cities = Cities::model()->findAll();
array_unshift($model_cities, array());
```

Comment: how do you want it to be rendered?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'user_city_id', CHtml::listData(Cities::model()->findAll(), 'city_id', 'city_name') , array('prompt'=>'Select City'));
?>
```

you can just, to get pair that u want to represent in your dropDownList:

```
Citites::model()->findAll(array('select'=>'city_id, city_name'));
```

above will render dropdown list with value (city_id), key (city_name), tell me if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: adding this line returns this error: 
call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, array must have exactly two members

Comment: I get this somehow
I removed 'city_country_id' from 
`CHtml::listData($model_cities, 'city_id', 'city_country_id','city_name')`
and now I am getting city value.

Comment: array('empty'=>'Select City') adding this line gives error.

Comment: @OmerJr i've edited answer try it now. (added array('prompt'=>''), instead of array('empty'=>''))

Comment: still getting error.  anyway, pair-value information was very helpful. thanks!